# How to assign new items to selected column in an existing Pandas csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a problem.  As a result, I get the last item. Please help.

```
df = pd.read_csv('patient_data_set_copy_test1.csv')
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['sex'] == 'Men':
        # df1 = pd.DataFrame(colors)
        row['height_p'] : random.randint(149, 192)
        row.to_csv('patient_data_set_copy_test1.csv', header=False)
```

This is start file CSV:

```
id,sex,age,weight_p,height_p,BMI,Smoke,Smoke_Years,Smoke_amount_day,Chol_All,LDL,HDL,Sugar1,Sugar2,Sugar3,Systolic_pressure,Diastolic_presurre,Likelihood_of_obesity,Likelihood_of_diabetes,Likelihood_of_coronary_heart_disease
0,Woman,45,,,,Nie,,,,,,,,,,,,,
1,Man,41,,,,Nie,,,,,,,,,,,,,
2,Woman,26,,,,Tak,,,,,,,,,,,,,
3,Men,72,,,,Nie,,,,,,,,,,,,,
4,Woman,69,,,,Tak,,,,,,,,,,,,,
.
.
.
11342, Man,41,,,,Nie,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

This is the result:

```
id,11357
sex,Men
age,82.0
weight_p,
height_p,173
BMI,
Smoke,Tak
Smoke_Years,
Smoke_amount_day,
Chol_All,
LDL,
HDL,
Sugar1,
Sugar2,
Sugar3,
Systolic_pressure,
Diastolic_presurre,
Likelihood_of_obesity,
Likelihood_of_diabetes,
Likelihood_of_coronary_heart_disease,
```

I would like to get the exact index of the selected man, and then update the CSV file.
Thanks for all the replies.

Comment: Can you give a reproducible example (_not the result of what you've tried_) and the exact matching output ?

Comment: The `Result` you put in your question is what you're looking for ? Or you need a dataframe with the same shape and updated values that you'll save to the initial `. csv` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update the height_p column for all rows in your DataFrame that have a sex of "Men" with a random integer between 149 and 192:

```py
import random

df = pd.read_csv('patient_data_set_copy_test1.csv')

# Iterate over the rows of the DataFrame
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['sex'] == 'Men':
        # Update the height_p column with a random integer between 149 and 192
        df.loc[index, 'height_p'] = random.randint(149, 192)

# Save the updated DataFrame to the CSV file
df.to_csv('patient_data_set_copy_test1.csv', header=True)
```